# FC on button action (if...toast)

Tags: android, toast

When i tap on button when editText are **empty** i have a FC, here is my code:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        float q1=Float.parseFloat(vol.getText().toString());
        float q2=Float.parseFloat(kil.getText().toString());
        String value1 = vol.getText().toString();
        String value2 = kil.getText().toString();
                if (value1 != null && value1.trim().length() > 0 && value2 != null && value2.trim().length() > 0)
                {
                    float x=((q1 / q2)* 100);
                    cons.setText(Float.toString(x));
                }
                else 
                {
                Toast.makeText(carburant.this, "Veuillez saisir le 1er champs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
      });
```

Comment: This has been answered. Please accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason could be because you are trying to parseFloat a null value. Try to obtain the values of q1 and q2 inside the if condition

Answer (score 1):

Actually, they will throw exceptions. Get them in a try catch block. Put it in try and handle it in catch. It is better because you can toast in the catch.

[Android parseFloat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29)

EDIT:
Here is some code.

```
try {
  flt1 = Float.parseFloat(str1);
  flt2 = Float.parseFloat(str2);
  result = flt1 + flt2;
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  // Do something to let user know it didnt work.
}
```

Comment: Okay, i'll try with try catch block and let you know . Thanks :).

Comment: It should work fine. if it works, come back and mark as accepted so other know. Also, look at the link to find the exception name.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, the conversion to float was bad placed, here is the working code:

```
String value1 = vol.getText().toString();
 String value2 = kil.getText().toString();
                     if (value1 != null && value1.trim().length() > 0 && value2 != null && value2.trim().length() > 0)
                     {
                             float q1=Float.parseFloat(vol.getText().toString());
                             float q2=Float.parseFloat(kil.getText().toString());
                             float x=((q1 / q2)* 100);
                             cons.setText(Float.toString(x));

                     }
                     else 
                     {
                     Toast.makeText(carburant.this, "Veuillez vérifier les deux champs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
```

Thank you for your help :).